# Type mismatch error when assigning values to an array

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to loop through a set of segments based on a specific merchant that is selected.

My issue arises when the code reaches the part of:

```
For j = 0 To merchantArraySize
out(j) = outnames(j).Value
Next j
```

This throws a type-mismatch error. It's strange because when looking in the watch window, the correct values are being assigned to out and outnames, it's just not allowing me to send the full array to it's destination.

```
Sub compute_merchant_segment_summary()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Dim program_range As Range
    Dim fico_range As Range
    Dim term_range As Range
    Dim band_range As Range

    Dim program_type As Range
    Dim fico_type As Range
    Dim term_type As Range
    Dim band_type As Range

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim out() As Long


    outnames = Array([I_LOAN_CODE], ..... 'total of 138 variables here)

    Dim merchantArraySize As Integer
    merchantArraySize = UBound(outnames) - LBound(outnames)

Set program_range =  Worksheets("Merchants").Range(Worksheets("Summary").Range("Merchant_Selection") & "_PROG")

    For Each program_type In program_range
        ReDim out(merchantArraySize)
        program_type.Copy
        Worksheets("Summary").Range("Program_Selection").Value = program_type
        Set term_range = Worksheets("Merchants").Range(Worksheets("Summary").Range("Merchant_Selection") & "_" & Worksheets("Summary").Range("term_new") & "_TERM")
        Set fico_range = Worksheets("Merchants").Range(Worksheets("Summary").Range("Merchant_Selection") & "_FICO")
        Set band_range = Worksheets("Merchants").Range(Worksheets("Summary").Range("Merchant_Selection") & "_BAND_SIZE")

            For Each term_type In term_range
                term_type.Copy
                Worksheets("Summary").Range("Term_Selection").Value = term_type

                    For Each fico_type In fico_range
                        fico_type.Copy
                        Worksheets("Summary").Range("FICO_Selection").Value = fico_type

                            For Each band_type In band_range
                                band_type.Copy
                                Worksheets("Summary").Range("Band_Selection").Value = band_type

                                    For j = 0 To merchantArraySize
                                        out(j) = outnames(j).Value
                                    Next j

                                    Worksheets("Loan Level").Activate
                                    Worksheets("Loan Level").Range(Cells(i + 1, 0), Cells(i + 1, 0 + merchantArraySize)) = out

                            Next band_type

                    Next fico_type

            Next term_type

    Next program_type
    End

End Sub
```

Comment: You declared `Dim out() As Long` where the array `outnames` is a Variant array, so the values even though they might seem correct, they are probably coming out as Strings in outnames and as such cannot allocate them into your `out` array, which is declared as being Long.

Comment: Change the declaration do `Dim out As Variant`

Comment: `'total of 138 variables here)` <~ that's some scary code/comment. Consider loading the array with a loop of some sort. The *smell* here, is that you're treating *data* as *code*, and that is a huge maintenance burden. Move the data out of the code (and into e.g. a spreadsheet)!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon had to vote you up just for **<~ that's some scary code/comment** comment :)